# How to distinct between proxies protocols in requests module in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I know how to use `proxies` in `requests` module in Python, but sometimes there is a proxy file which I can't distinct among `http`, `https` and `ftp` proxies to put them correctly in dictionary.

```py
proxies = {
    "http": 'ip:port'
}
```

How can I understand for example this line proxy is `http` or next one is `https`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http` in this case is not protocol of the proxy. It's which proxy will handle this schema. If you want to handle all traffic with the same proxy just enumerate all used protocols (schemas of URLs that you use) with the same proxy setting.

```
{
    "http": 'ip:port',
    "https": 'ip:port',
}
```